# Mule VMQUEUE default size and how it increases or decreases its size

Tags: queue, mule

I have doubts that how vm queue in mule is created. What is the default size. Is it static or dynamic. If there are more messages in the queue than the default size, will it increase its size dynamically or the messages will be lost. When the messages are taken from vm inbound, will the memory is released back to the JVM and the size vm queue decreases.

Please respond to the following
When the vm queue is created at first, what is the default memory size ? 2. How the size in memory increases 3. How the size in memory decrease. When there are no messages, the queue get destroyed or still remains in memory with some default memory size ?

Answer (score 0):

It's good to read the documentation:

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/VM+Transport+Reference

`maxOutstandingMessages`: Defines the maximum number of messages that can be queued. The default, 0, means there is no limit on the number of messages that can be queued.

Comment: How it works, when we keep the maxOutstandingMessages default. I m not getting all the answers of my question in the given link.

Comment: What question remains unanswered?

Comment: 1. When the vm queue is created at first, what is the default memory size ? 2. How the size in memory increases 3. How the size in memory decrease. When there are no messages, the queue get destroyed or still remains in memory with some default memory size ?

Comment: @msm Great questions. Did you get any answers for this? Kindly share.